# The webpage loads for ever after submitting the form when using firebase authentication

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using firebase authentication in my website and when the user insert its data and click the button to submit the form the new user created successfully in firebase but the form loads forever and it doesn't move to the next page . I tried a lot to find the problem but I couldn't find a solution to this.

This is the code in the HTML file :

```
    <body>

    <div class="main">

      <!-- Sign up form -->
        <section class="signup">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="signup-content">
                    <div class="signup-form">
                        <h2 class="form-title">Sign up</h2>
                        <form method="POST" class="register-form" id="register-form">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="name"><i class="zmdi zmdi-account material-icons-name"></i></label>
                                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Your Name" required=" Name" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="email"><i class="zmdi zmdi-email"></i></label>
                                <input type="email" name="email" id="userEmail" placeholder="Your Email" required="Email" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="pass"><i class="zmdi zmdi-lock"></i></label>
                                <input type="password" name="pass" id="userPassword" placeholder="Password" required="password" minlength=6/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="re-pass"><i class="zmdi zmdi-lock-outline"></i></label>
                                <input type="password" name="re_pass" id="confirmPassword" placeholder="Confirm your password" required="Please confirm your password" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
<select required="" id="gove">
    <option value="" hidden="hidden" disabled  selected>Governorate</option>
    <option value="alexandria">Alexandria</option>
    <option value="aswan">Aswan</option>
    <option value="asyut">Asyut</option>
    <option value="beheira">Beheira</option>
    <option value="beheirasuef">Beheira Suef</option>
    <option value="cairo">Cairo</option>
    <option value="dakahlia">Dakahlia</option>
    <option value="damietta">Damietta</option>
    <option value="faiyum">Faiyum</option>
    <option value="gharbia">Gharbia</option>
    <option value="ismailia">Ismailia</option>
    <option value="kafrelsheikh">Kafr El Sheikh</option>
    <option value="luxor">Luxor</option>
    <option value="matruh">Matruh</option>
    <option value="minya">Minya</option>
    <option value="monufia">Monufia</option>
    <option value="newvalley">New Valley</option>
    <option value="northsinai">North Sinai</option>
    <option value="portsaid">portsaid</option>
    <option value="qalyubia">Qalyubia</option>
    <option value="qena">Qena</option>
    <option value="redsea">Red Sea</option>
    <option value="sharqia">Sharqia</option>
    <option value="sohag">Sohag</option>
    <option value="southsinai">South Sinai</option>
    <option value="suez">Suez</option>

</select></div>      
<!--                          <div class="form-group">

<select required="" id="gen">
    <option value="" hidden="hidden" disabled  selected>Gender</option>
    <option value="Male">Male</option>
    <option value="Female">Female</option>


</div> -->

                            <div class="form-group form-button">
                                <input type="submit" name="signup" id="signup" onclick="createUser();" class="form-submit" value="Sign Up"/>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="signup-image">
                        <figure><img src="images/signup-image.jpg" alt="sing up image"></figure>
                        <a href="index.html" class="signup-image-link">I am already member</a>
                                                <div class="social-login">
                          <!-- Google login button
                                <span class="social-label">Or Sign Up with</span>
                            <ul class="socials">
                                <li><a href="#" onclick="GoogleLogin();"><i class="display-flex-center zmdi zmdi-google"></i></a></li>
                            </ul>
                             -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>


    </div>

            <!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.4.1/firebase-app.js"></script>

<!-- Add additional services that you want to use -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.9.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>

<!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
     https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#config-web-app -->

<script>
  // Your web app's Firebase configuration
  var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyDf81QdVH8JDM1NVJAMMIOzqlnakkV5x_o",
    authDomain: "enjoylearning-a3ce3.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://enjoylearning-a3ce3.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "enjoylearning-a3ce3",
    storageBucket: "enjoylearning-a3ce3.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "697151736213",
    appId: "1:697151736213:web:53aa9dd05575f3a3"
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
</script>

</script>
    <!-- JS -->
    <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/google.js"></script>
    <script src="js/SignUp.js"></script>

</body>
```

and this is the code in the JavaScript file :

```
//validate that both passwords are same
if(password==confirmPassword && username != "" && email != "" && password != ""
    && confirmPassword != "" && gove != "")
{

    //Here we will write create Account code
    //firebase has its own built in create account method
    //lets start
    //it takes two param first one email and second is password
 firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).then(
        function () {
            //this function executes when account is successfully created

            window.location="home.html";
            console.log("User Successfully created")

    }).catch(function (error) {
       //this function handles errors
        var errorMessage=error.message;
        console.log(errorMessage);
    });

} else {
    console.log("There is a problem in the data");
}
```

Comment: Is there console output? Like does any of your messages come up or an error message? And can you post your html containing the complete form?

Comment: No errors come in the log

Comment: Does `"User Successfully created"` come up?

Comment: Yes , this message appears in the console

Comment: I'm pretty sure your redirect isnt working. Try `document.location.href="/";` instead of `window.location="home.html";`.

Comment: @acincognito it gives the same result